# URL Rewrite not working

Tags: category, url-rewrite

I am trying to add in a url redirect in the admin system so I can bypass a category page to go straight to the product as there is only 1 product in that category. In the Catalog => URL Rewrite Management section I have the following entered:

> Type - Custom
>   ID Path - `category/15`
>   Request Path - `labels`
>   Target Path - `labels/a4.html`
>   Redirect - Yes

But when I go to the `labels` page it doesn't redirect. I know that it definitely has a category ID of 15 and that the `labels/a4.html` is correct

Answer (score 1):

The value of the Request Path should be the path when you go to the "labels" category in your browser, which I'm going to guess is "labels.html" based on your product settings (though there are two separate URL suffix settings for products and categories).

Comment: Help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/219953/57334