# Is Possible Main Category URL Rewrite Management?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-rewrite

My Category Name : `Test`

**URL Rewrite Management**

[image]

In Localhost If i click the category name **Test**, the URL redirect to `http://194.0.0.24/abcd/catalog/category/view/id/30`

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: What are you wanting the url to be when you click the test category?

Comment: If customer click my category called Test, it redirect to google page.

Comment: category edit page add url_key and save that category

Comment: @zus I believe you want the target path to be the url that you want the category directed to.

Comment: @AJ47 If i do what you told, i am getting result like, https://snag.gy/rw4UlQ.jpg

Comment: @AJ47 And my website url like https://snag.gy/W0Ca4w.jpg

Comment: @zus In your first screenshot can you try updating your custom ID path to something unique like `catalog/30` and keep everything else the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect test category to google by following below steps:

1. set your main category url rewrite to "Temporary 302".
2. create a custom url rewrite in that enter

   - ID Path * = test-idpath (any unique path)
   - Request Path * = catalog/category/view/id/4 (your category path)
   - Target Path * =   http://google.com
   - Redirect = "Permanent 301"

Comment: Not working, Screen shot -> https://snag.gy/8EYw0K.jpg

Comment: Category Name : Go,  If i click Go, the url like -> http://127.0.0.1/abc/www.google.com

Comment: Add "http://"  in target URL.